# Can't install AIR on Galaxy Android device

Tags: adobe-air

I'm doing some AIR for Android development. When I try and launch my app, I am told I need to install Adobe AIR. After being taken to the Google Play site, I get the message that "Your device isn't compatible with this version."

I updated my OS on my Galaxy Tab 10.1 to Android 4.04, but I still get this message. How can I get Adobe AIR installed?

Answer (score 1):

From the [system requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html) for Adobe Air 3:

- ARMv7 processor with vector FPU, minimum 550MHz, OpenGL ES 2.0, H.264 and AAC HW decoders
- Android™ 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, or 4.0
- 256MB of RAM
- Android web browser

Comment: How does this actually answer the question?